# Search function in "Open files" dialog has gone missing in any browser

Tags: nautilus, firefox, google-chrome, search, dialog

When I, for instance, want to upload an e-mail attachment in a browser, I click "attach" and then a file dialog opens, which is the same in bot Chrome and Firefox, and probably any browser in Ubuntu.

I always used the search function to immediately find the file I was looking for. Most of the time, entering three or four characters is enough.

But now all of a sudden (I assume after a Nautilus update?) this function is no longer there. Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does open a search bar, but after typing one character, the cursor disappears. This makes it very awkward to use.

Is there a solution to this? It really impedes my workflow.